# Writing type for firebase functions/storgae/database in interface

Tags: typescript

What would be the typescript types for firebase functions/storage/admin?

So I am new to typescript, and was updating my code JS code to typescript.

In my code, I am creating context obj

```
const context = {
    functions: functions,
    realtime: admin.database(),
    firestore: admin.firestore()
    admin: admin
}
```

Now, I am passing this context and I want to create interface for it? Can someone help me in figuring out the interface for the above? And in-general, How do you determine types of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe TS is able to *infer* the type of `context` object automatically, with `typeof` keyword.

```
// keep the code as-is:
const context = {
    functions: functions,
    realtime: admin.database(),
    firestore: admin.firestore()
    admin: admin
}

// then add:
type IContext = typeof context
```

You can safely pass this interface around. No need to manually declare it unless you need to tailor-made it to meet specific requirement.

Comment: Even when I don't declare interface for context, the typescript doesn't complain about it. As a typescript developer would you create interface?

Comment: @anny123 what is currently broken that you seek to fix? I don't get what you're asking.

Comment: I was primarily asking for interface for the above.

Comment: I am more-less curious to know that as a typescript developer, when would you create interface for objects?

Comment: @anny123 Most of the time I just let TS infers the type. Some of the case where I would do `const obj: SomePredefinedInterface = {...}`, it usually means the interface is more general than the current `obj` instance, and used multiple times elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just define your interface base on property types.
The `firestore` is `admin.firestore.Firestore` interface, the same for each other.

This is my example with firebase admin (I don't know what is the `functions`):

```
import firebaseAdmin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

interface IContext {
  realtime: admin.database.Database;
  firestore: admin.firestore.Firestore;
  admin: typeof firebaseAdmin;
}

// then
const context: IContext = {
  realtime: admin.database(),
  firestore: admin.firestore(),
  admin,
};
```